# GET error 400 bad request on second axios api call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to get data from an API using Axios. I have two API calls. The first call runs fine, and I get the data I expect. The second one, however, comes back with the 400 error bad request.

I've searched through multiple forums to try and find a solution, but I don't quite understand the code that I find.

```
    const [player, setPlayer] = useState([]);
    const [newPlayer, setNewPlayer] = useState([]);

    const FindLoadout = async () => {
        await axios.get(`http://api.paladins.com/paladinsapi.svc/getmatchidsbyqueueJson/${devId}/${generateSignature('getmatchidsbyqueue')}/${props.sess}/${moment.utc().format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss')}/428/${moment.utc().format('YYYYMMDD')}/-1,00`).then((response) => {
                const playerData = response.data;
                playerData.map((el) => {
                    player.push(el.Match)
                })
                console.log(player);
                for(let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                    newPlayer.push(player[i]);
                }
                console.log(newPlayer);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
            axios.get(`http://api.paladins.com/paladinsapi.svc/getmatchdetailsbatchJson/${devId}/${generateSignature('getmatchdetailsbatch')}/${props.sess}/${moment.utc().format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss')}/${newPlayer.join(",")}`).then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
```

The error message is:

> Error: Request failed with status code 400
>       at createError (createError.js:17)
>       at settle (settle.js:19)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:60)

Comment: Code sample is incomplete: `player` and `newPlayer` aren't defined.

Comment: Edited, thank you.

Comment: Not sure if it's the only issue here, since this is pretty API-specific and you've not included code for `generateSignature` etc., but you're not using the `useState` hook correctly. The second value it returns is how it's supposed to be updated, like: `setPlayer(myUpdatedValue)`: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it will exactly address your problem, but when using `async` / `await` for data fetching, a common practice is to do it more like this :

```
const FindLoadout = async () => {

  const playerData= await axios
    .get(`http://api.paladins.com/player/154`)
    .then(response => response.data);

  const gameData= await axios
    .get(`http://api.paladins.com/game/788`)
    .then(response => response.data);

  return {player: playerData, game: gamedata}
}
```

That is to say, you **assign** the data fetched by your API calls to variables, and then **return** the data that you need from them (after whatever manipulation you deem necessary).

The ability to write asynchronous code in that kind of synchronous syntax is one of the most appealing trait of `async` / `await`.

I suspect the errors you get are because you second call does not have the `await` keyword before it is fired.

EDIT : also, as other have remarked, you are definitely going to encounter issues with your incorrect use of hooks, but this is not the scope of the question.

Comment: Doing this seems to break my code for some reason. Even previous API calls are no longer working. I have them set up in the same way you mentioned above. EDIT: It doesn't actually break it, just makes it take longer. I am still receiving the 400 error however.

Comment: Can you try to remove the state management through hooks and only fire the API calls, assign the returned data to variables,  and log those variables? Just to have the minimal example of the bug. 

A 400 error probably means you are providing a wrong path for one of your API calls.

Comment: Only the first call needs to be awaited. The second is simply logging using `then`. But yeah, `await` _instead_ of `then` is better :)

Comment: Well, even if it's only logging the response, it is still firing an API call, and therefore is by nature an asynchronous bit of code, that should be `await`ed. Unless I fundamentally misunderstand something.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you are mixing async and traditional promises

[EDIT: you are also mutating state directly instead of using setState]

[EDIT2: setting state is not immediate therefor a console.log of state (and the axios get request relying on the state value) directly after a setState will not usually log the value you anticipate and therefore should be included inside the callback function passed to setState -or- utilize useEffect when the state does update]

[EDIT3: build new state outside of loop then setState after]

```
const [player, setPlayer] = useState([]);
const [newPlayer, setNewPlayer] = useState([]);
const FindLoadout = async () => {
    useEffect(()=>{
        if (!player.length) return
        const newState = [...newPlayer]
        for(let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            newState.push(player[i]);
        }
        setNewPlayer(newState)
    }, [player]);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!newPlayer.length) return 
         axios
            .get(`http://api.paladins.com/paladinsapi.svc/getmatchdetailsbatchJson/${devId}/${generateSignature('getmatchdetailsbatch')}/${props.sess}/${moment.utc().format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss')}/${newPlayer.join(",")}`)
            .then((gameData)=>{
                console.log(gameData)
            }).catch((error)=>{
                console.error(error)
            })
    }, [newPlayer]);
    try {
        const playerData= await axios.get(`http://api.paladins.com/paladinsapi.svc/getmatchidsbyqueueJson/${devId}/${generateSignature('getmatchidsbyqueue')}/${props.sess}/${moment.utc().format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss')}/428/${moment.utc().format('YYYYMMDD')}/-1,00`)
        const newState = [...player]
        playerData.map((el) => newState.push(el.Match))
        setPlayer(newState)
    }catch(error) {
        console.error(error);
    } 
}
```

If you want to stick with asyc for the second useEffect you can also use a callback instead:
https://dev.to/n1ru4l/homebrew-react-hooks-useasynceffect-or-how-to-handle-async-operations-with-useeffect-1fa8

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (!newPlayer.length) return
        const myCallback = async ()=>{
            try{
                const gameData = await axios.get(`http://api.paladins.com/paladinsapi.svc/getmatchdetailsbatchJson/${devId}/${generateSignature('getmatchdetailsbatch')}/${props.sess}/${moment.utc().format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss')}/${newPlayer.join(",")}`)
                console.log(gameData)
            }catch(error){
                console.error(error)
            }
        }
        myCallback()
}, [newPlayer]);
```

If that doesn't fix the issue:

> The 400 Bad Request error is an HTTP status code that means that the
>   request you sent to the website server was somehow incorrect or corrupted and the server couldn't understand it.

ie: Your URL is incorrect for the API call I would double check that the "generateSignature" function is returning the proper value. If that is the case I would check to make sure that newPlayer.join(",") is returning the proper value.

Comment: I changed the async functions to the way you have presented here. I've checked all variables that I supply to the URL and they all look correct. I've tried entering in the %5C%2C and also %2C in the join method. This gives me the 404 error, not found.

Comment: please check my current edits: you were not setting state properly and you were trying to access state directly after setting it

Comment: edited again to include useEffect which is a cleaner approach than setState callbacks

Comment: also im not sure if you mean to but your newPlayer state will end up having lots of duplicates (every time you are adding a player you are adding every player to the newPlayer array even if its already there)

Comment: This is giving me an error saying that I cannot use "await" outside of an async function. I have them nested just as you do in your code above. Also the newPlayer is to get a smaller data sample from the player array.

Comment: you appear to be ADDING the results of the playerData request to the player array, then you are ADDING every player to the newPlayerArray within the first useEffect. ----- if this function runs again you will be Adding all the players from the playerData request to the end of the player state array then you will be adding the the entire player array (new elements and old elements) to the newPlayers state array in the second useEffect. this appears to be same concept as your original code snippet when you mutated state with push()

Comment: I now keep getting an error saying Invalid hook call

Comment: sorry brain fart. useEffect cannot use async directly, you must either use a conventional promise or use an async callback function (both are added to my edited answer)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with how you are assigning values to `player` and `newPlayer`. Since you are using the `useState` hook you are supposed to use `setPlayer` and `setNewPlayer`.

Could you tell me what's the value of `newPlayer` before the second api call?

Maybe you could update it like this:

```js
const FindLoadout = async () => {
        await axios.get(`http://api.paladins.com/paladinsapi.svc/getmatchidsbyqueueJson/${devId}/${generateSignature('getmatchidsbyqueue')}/${props.sess}/${moment.utc().format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss')}/428/${moment.utc().format('YYYYMMDD')}/-1,00`).then((response) => {
                const playerData = response.data;
                //playerData.map((el) => {
                //    player.push(el.Match)
                //})
                setPlayer(playerData.map(el) => el.Match);
                console.log(player);
                //for(let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                //    newPlayer.push(player[i]);
                //}
                // I'm not sure how to update this assignment
                console.log(newPlayer);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
            axios.get(`http://api.paladins.com/paladinsapi.svc/getmatchdetailsbatchJson/${devId}/${generateSignature('getmatchdetailsbatch')}/${props.sess}/${moment.utc().format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss')}/${newPlayer.join(",")}`).then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
```

About updating `newPlayer`: since states are updated asynchronously, by the time you try to update `newPlayer` using the values in `player`, `player` has nothing in it.

Try to make the request with some hardcoded values to see if the problem is with the api requests or with the values in your variables.